# Is there a good way to match a pattern or at beginning of a string?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all numbers which is:

1. After a '#'
2. At the beginning

For example,

```
>>> s = '1___2___#3___@4___##5'
```

The result should be

```
['1', '3', '5']
```

What I have now is

```
>>> re.findall('#(\d)', s)          # ['3', '5']
```

And

```
>>> re.findall('^(\d)', s)          # ['1']
```

But I don't know how to combine them into one regular expression. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep it simple...

`re.findall` gives the first preference to capturing groups. So put the preceding `^` (*starting anchor*) and `#` inside a non-capturing group.

```
>>> s = '1___2___#3___@4___##5'
>>> re.findall('(?:^|#)(\d+)', s)
['1', '3', '5']
```

**OR**

Much simpler..

```
>>> s = '1___2___#3___@4___##5'
>>> re.findall('(?<![^#])\d+', s)
['1', '3', '5']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/57)

Here is how the above regex would work...

- `(?<!.)\d+` Matches all the numbers which aren't preceded by a character (*except line breaks*). So this must match the number which was present at the start, because the at the start only satisfies this condition.
- `(?<![^#])\d+` Again one step further, this regex would match the number which was present at the start, since `[^#]` consume a character and it also matches all the numbers which aren't preceded by a character not of `#`.

Answer (score 5):

```
^\d+|(?<=#)\d+
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/51

Use

```
re.findall('^\d+|(?<=#)\d+', s)
```

Capture only what you need by using `0 width assertions`.

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                       the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #                        '#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                       the most amount possible))
```